# Is it possible to create Dev/Test subscription in Azure Government cloud (EA)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-gov

Can we create Dev/Test subscription in Azure Government cloud as part of Enterprise Agreement (EA)? I am unable to test it as my organization does not gave me enough permission to test it under Azure Gov Tenant. Has anyone able to create Dev/Test subscription in Azure Gov Cloud?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.

Answer (score -1):

provided your organization has a government enterprise agreement, you should be able to create subscriptions for whatever purposes your organization allows in Azure Government. Do you know your enterprise agreement administrator? They should be able to ensure you're assigned access to create subscriptions that are billed to the right department within your organization.

Comment: Following up on this, if you're talking about Enterprise Dev/Test subscriptions (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0148p/), Azure Government does not support these at this time.